# Matlab - set the colororder to default

Tags: matlab

I am plotting data using the follow code

```
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x2,y2)
```

and the plots are always blue. What ever I try to change the color order property with the following code:

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesColorOrder',co)
```

where co is a RGB matrix, than I check the color order with the following function:

```
get(0, 'DefaultAxesColorOrder')
get(gca,'colororder')
```

both return the matrix that I set globally before which is expected but the plot always remain blue what ever I do with the function to set color order property

[EDIT #1]
Here is the output for the get function

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your RGB matrix ?

Comment: @Coriolis there you go. I took it from a matwork's forum, the answer mentionned it was a default matrix for Matlab 2014R I think. We can see that it isn't the same color everywhere.

Comment: You must be using an older version of MATLAB, in that case you need to use `hold all` instead of `hold on`. I think this was changed from 2014b onwards

Comment: @Dan I tried that and it didn't work..

Comment: I figure it out. There is a conflit when I try to gave the same style to 2 differents set of data. Matlab give the same color to both set of data because the line style is already set with 1 color.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me (MATLAB R2015a) except I set the color **before** plotting. It seems that the `set` command does not update your plot because it may not understand the plot handle.
I tried this :

```
figure;
co = [0 0 0; 0.4, 0.4, 0.4; 0.7, 0.7, 0.7];
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',co)
plot([1 2],[1 2])
hold on;
plot([1,2],[1,3])
```

It displays a black line and a grey line.